# Hadoop & Bash: delete filenames matching range

Tags: bash, hadoop

Say you have a list of files in HDFS with a common prefix and an incrementing suffix. For example,

```
part-1.gz, part-2.gz, part-3.gz, ..., part-50.gz
```

I only want to leave a few file in the directory, say 3. Any three files will do. The files will be used for testing so the choice of files doesn't matter.

What's the simples & fastest way to delete the 47 other files?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Few options here:

---

Move three files manually over to a new folder, then delete the old folder.

---

Grab the files names with `fs -ls`, then pull the top n, then rm them. This is the most robust method, in my opinion.

`hadoop fs -ls /path/to/files` gives you ls output

`hadoop fs -ls /path/to/files | grep 'part' | awk '{print $8}'` prints out only the file names (adjust the grep accordingly to grab the files you want).

`hadoop fs -ls /path/to/files | grep 'part' | awk '{print $8}' | head -n47` grabs the top 47

Throw this into a for loop and rm them:

```
for k in `hadoop fs -ls /path/to/files | grep part | awk '{print $8}' | head -n47`
do
   hadoop fs -rm $k
done
```

---

Instead of a for-loop, you could use `xargs`:

```
hadoop fs -ls /path/to/files | grep part | awk '{print $8}' | head -n47 | xargs hadoop fs -rm
```

Thanks to Keith for the inspiration

Comment: `hadoop fs -ls | grep part | awk '{print $8}' | head -n47 | xargs -I {} hadoop fs -rm {}` maybe?

Comment: By security, always use a for loop, and prefix path like this ``hadoop fs -rm /PATH.../$file`` so there is no chance to remove something else.

Answer (score 4):

In Bash?

What files do you want to keep and why? What are their names? In the above example, you could do something like this:

```
$ rm !(part-[1-3].gz)
```

which will remove all files except part-1.gz, part-2.gz, and part-3.gz.

You can also do something like this:

```
$ rm $(ls | sed -n '4,$p')
```

Which will remove all except the last three files listed.

You could also do this:

```
$ls | sed -n '4,$p' | xargs rm
```

Which is safer if you have hundreds and hundreds of files in the directory.

Answer (score 3):

Do you need to keep the *first* three or the *last* three?

To remove all but the first three:

```
hadoop fs -ls | grep 'part-[0-9]*\.gz' | sort -g -k2 -t- | tail -n +4 | xargs -r -d\\n hadoop fs -rm
```

To remove all but the last three:

```
hadoop fs -ls | grep 'part-[0-9]*\.gz' | sort -g -k2 -t- | head -n -3 | xargs -r -d\\n hadoop fs -rm
```

Note that these commands don't depend on the actual number of files, nor on the existence of more than three, nor on the precise sorting of the original listing, but they do depend on the fact that the number is after a hyphen.  The parameters to `xargs` aren't strictly necessary, but they may be helpful in certain situations.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls part-*.gz | sed -e "1,3d" | xargs rm
```

Comment: hadoop has a different interface than your traditional ls/rm/etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response, very useful. I edited the question to place more emphasis on HDFS though.

Comment: The question didn't mention HDFS when I wrote my answer. Should I delete it?

Comment: Look at my answer and tell me if i can do what I did with xargs. it seems cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

awk :

```
  ls part-*.gz|awk -F '[-\.]' '$2>3{print "rm "$0}' |sh
```