# Finding directories older than N days in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Can hadoop fs -ls be used to find all directories older than N days (from the current date)?

I am trying to write a clean up routine to find and delete all directories on HDFS (matching a pattern) which were created N days prior to the current date.

Comment: One of the earlier solutions was partially helpful. I could write a shell script to find and delete all the directories matching a pattern but what I really needed to do was delete just the ones that were older than N days. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733096/hadoop-bash-delete-filenames-matching-range)

Answer (score 18):

This script lists all the directories that are older than `[days]` :

```
#!/bin/bash
usage="Usage: $0 [days]"

if [ ! "$1" ]
then
  echo $usage
  exit 1
fi

now=$(date +%s)
hadoop fs -lsr | grep "^d" | while read f; do 
  dir_date=`echo $f | awk '{print $6}'`
  difference=$(( ( $now - $(date -d "$dir_date" +%s) ) / (24 * 60 * 60 ) ))
  if [ $difference -gt $1 ]; then
    echo $f;
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 7):

If you happen to be using `CDH` distribution of Hadoop, it comes with a very useful [HdfsFindTool](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/search_hdfsfindtool.html) command, which behaves like Linux's `find` command.

If you're using the default parcels information, here's how you'd do it:

```
hadoop jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars/search-mr-*-job.jar \
org.apache.solr.hadoop.HdfsFindTool -find PATH -mtime +N
```

Where you'd replace PATH with the search path and N with number of days.

Comment: A kind note: HdfsFindTool is deprecated from CDH 6.X

Answer (score 4):

For real clusters it is not a good idea,
to use ls. If you have admin rights, 
it is more suitable to use fsimage.

I modify script above to illustrate idea.

first, fetch fsimage

```
curl "http://localhost:50070/getimage?getimage=1&txid=latest" > img.dump
```

convert it to text (same output as lsr gives)

```
hdfs oiv -i img.dump -o fsimage.txt
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
usage="Usage: dir_diff.sh [days]"

if [ ! "$1" ]
then
  echo $usage
  exit 1
fi

now=$(date +%s)
curl "http://localhost:50070/getimage?getimage=1&txid=latest" > img.dump
hdfs oiv -i img.dump -o fsimage.txt
cat fsimage.txt | grep "^d" | while read f; do 
  dir_date=`echo $f | awk '{print $6}'`
  difference=$(( ( $now - $(date -d "$dir_date" +%s) ) / (24 * 60 * 60 ) ))
  if [ $difference -gt $1 ]; then
    echo $f;
  fi
done
```

Comment: Could you explain please why it's better to use fsimage?

Comment: If you have millions files 'fs -ls'  probably wouldn't work. So you might either write your own java code to iterate filesystem or dump fsimage once and run many subsequent operations using it and simple unix tools.

Answer (score 3):

hdfs dfs -ls /hadoop/path/*.txt|awk '$6 < "2017-10-24"'

Comment: please give a proper explanation to your answer.

Comment: hdfs dfs -ls /hadoop/path/*.txt - This part will search all .txt files

awk '$6< "2017-10-24"'- this part will check for create date of file with condition.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't have the `HdfsFindTool`, nor the `fsimage` from `curl`, and I didn't much like the `ls` to `grep` with `while` loop using `date` `awk` and `hadoop` and `awk` again.
But I appreciated the answers.

I felt like it could be done with just one `ls`, one `awk`, and maybe an `xargs`.

I also added the options to list the files or summarize them before choosing to delete them, as well as choose a specific directory. Lastly I leave the directories and only concern myself about the files.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
USAGE="Usage: $0 [N days] (list|size|delete) [path, default /tmp/hive]"
if [ ! "$1" ]; then
  echo $USAGE
  exit 1
fi
AGO="`date --date "$1 days ago" "+%F %R"`"

echo "# Will search for files older than $AGO"
if [ ! "$2" ]; then
  echo $USAGE
  exit 1
fi
INPATH="${3:-/tmp/hive}"

echo "# Will search under $INPATH"
case $2 in
  list)
    hdfs dfs -ls -R "$INPATH" |\
      awk '$1 ~ /^[^d]/ && ($6 " " $7) < '"\"$AGO\""
  ;;
  size)
    hdfs dfs -ls -R "$INPATH" |\
      awk '$1 ~ /^[^d]/ && ($6 " " $7) < "'"$AGO"'" {
           sum += $5 ; cnt += 1} END {
           print cnt, "Files with total", sum, "Bytes"}'
  ;;
  delete)
    hdfs dfs -ls -R "$INPATH" |\
      awk '$1 ~ /^[^d]/ && ($6 " " $7) < "'"$AGO"'" {print $8}' | \
      xargs hdfs dfs -rm -skipTrash
  ;;
  *)
    echo $USAGE
    exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

I hope others find this useful.