# How to delete the data older than x days in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

How to delete a data older than x days.In `linux` its pretty simple,however in `hdfs` finding difficulty.

Moreover even `hdfs dfs -ls /<path>` is giving an unsorted ordered data.

Comment: You need to write a shell script for this. Solution is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613848/finding-directories-older-than-n-days-in-hdfs)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet to do so:

```
days_diff=10
now=$(date +%s)
hdfs dfs  -ls /path/todir/ | while read f; do
  dir_date=`echo $f | awk '{print $6}'`
  filename=`echo $f | awk '{print $8}'`
  difference=$(( ( $now - $(date -d "$dir_date" +%s) ) / (24 * 60 * 60 ) ))
  if [ $difference -gt $days_diff ]; then
    echo "Deleting file:" $filename ;
    hdfs dfs  -rm $filename;
  fi
done
```