# hdfs remove directories older than 7 days

Tags: shell, hadoop, hdfs

I have archive directory structure like 
`/archivedData/Mappings/Web/NOW/`,
where `NOW` is current date:
`NOW=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")`.

I have to delete `NOW` directories older than 7 days from hdfs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding directories older than N days in HDFS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613848/finding-directories-older-than-n-days-in-hdfs)

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved via `awk` and `date` command, below is the shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
 hadoop fs -ls /archivedData/Mappings/Web/NOW/| while read path; 
 do
 dir_date=`echo $path | awk '{print $6}'`|cut -d'/' -f5
 purge_criteria=`date +"%Y%m%d%H%M" --date "7 days ago"`
        if [ $dir_date -lt $purge_criteria ]; then
            hadoop fs -rm $f
        fi
 done
```